# move shortcut to mark an answer "Best Reply" in a discussion board

Tags: 2013, discussion-board, discussion

The option to mark an answer as "Best Reply" is buried inside the "..." in an answer on a discussion board. I want to bring it out of the "..." and make it easier to see/access. Maybe right before the "Like" and "Reply" options.

Is there anyway to do this?

[image]